# how to print ¢ (cents) symbol with star micronics iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing

i have **star micronics TSP650 (Bluetooth and Desktop interface), T300i Bluetooth Printer** and i'm implementing iOS SDK in my app, but i cant print the ¢ (cents) symbol

someone knows what is the code to print it?

Thanks

Comment: You can try with static string "¢" (Alt+4). If your printer/SDK support ascii then you can print with ascii character `(ASCII CODE 189)`. You can find other ascii code from this link [link] http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/cent-symbol-ascii-code-189.html

Comment: @Vivek Tried - Star Printer only prints ASCII control characters and ASCII printable characters not support Extended ASCII

Comment: Did you try with static string ¢ (Alt+4) ?

Comment: yes, its not works

Comment: Please open this pdf and go to page number (How to use  extended characters) 9 : http://www.starmicronics.com/support/Mannualfolder/mobile_pm_en15.pdf

Comment: One more link how to use Extended ascii for printer : http://docplayer.net/23884122-The-first-32-characters-in-the-ascii-table-are-unprintable-control-codes-and-are-used-to-control-peripherals-such-as-printers.html

Comment: Thanks for ur help - Ans Updated - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50014355/3560390

Comment: Is this working ? with this URL : http://docplayer.net/23884122-The-first-32-characters-in-the-ascii-table-are-unprintable-control-codes-and-are-used-to-control-peripherals-such-as-printers.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169743/discussion-between-vivek-and-prasath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code to print ¢ symbol is

```
[commands appendBytes:"\x9b" length:sizeof("\x9b")];
```

Here is the reference link for other symbols.

> URL:
>   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Interpretation_of_code_points_1%E2%80%9331_and_127